# Javascript time plus seconds?

Tags: jquery

**Let's say current time is 24:56:04**

And I want to do something like this:

```
variable time = current time (24:56:04) + 6 seconds.

If current time = or higher than time: print 'Success'

else print 'Fail'.
```

***Is it possible to do it this way? how?***

The other answer does not answer my question. Because I need to know if curret time = previous time + 10 seconds.

Comment: You're hoping that first line will take over 6 seconds to execute one day? ;)

Comment: _If current time = or higher than time_ ? higher that what time ?

Comment: Higher than Variable time. Variable time = current time + 6 seconds

Comment: You need to reword this question, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right I would use something like:

```
var t = Math.Round(new Date.getTime()/1000) + 6;
//operations or what here
if(Math.Round(new Date().getTime()/1000) >= t)
//Print success
else
//Print false
```

Of course you can skip rounding and dividing part, leaving you with faster and more accurate measurement (1ms accuracy)